# AutoComplete jquery from database

Tags: php, jquery, database, autocomplete

i have some problem with my code.

the html

```
<div class="input-group">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="search">
</div>
```

The data.php

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/jakarta");
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "dbautocomplete";

$koneksi = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname)or die("error koneksi");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
 echo 'Gagal melakukan koneksi ke Database : '.mysqli_connect_error();
}

$row_set = array();

$term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['q']));

$qstring = "SELECT * FROM tbl_auto WHERE nama_anime LIKE '".$term."%'";
$result = mysqli_query($koneksi,$qstring);
$found=mysqli_num_rows($result);

if($found>0) {
 while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

     $row['value']=htmlentities(stripslashes($row['nama_anime']));
     $row['id']=(int)$row['id'];
     $row_set[] = $row;

 }
}else{

 $row_set[]='Not found...';

}
echo json_encode($row_set);
```

The Jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        /*autocomplete muncul setelah user mengetikan minimal2 karakter */
        $(function() {  
            $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
                source: "data.php",  

            });
        });
    });
```

I already try to fix this code, but there is no response after I input some character in the field.
Please help me to find the issue. 
I already to search from many web, but i still cant find the rootcause.

Comment: 1st check should be the ajax response. Check the developers tools and check the response which should give you more insight

Comment: @Bsienn how to check it? sorry,, but i'm new in this case...

Comment: Press F12 to open developer tools in browser then select network tab and in that tab filter to XHR, there would be list of ajax calls. Click any one call and a panel would open. In that check the response tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, the autocomplete accept parameter name `term` not `q`

The html

```
<div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search">
</div>
```

The data.php

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/jakarta");
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$dbname = "dbautocomplete";

try {
    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname) or die("error connecting database");

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo 'Gagal melakukan conn ke Database : '.mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $term = trim(strip_tags($_GET['term']));

    $qry = "SELECT * FROM nama_anime WHERE nama_anime LIKE '".$term."%'";
    $query  = mysqli_query($conn, $qry);

    if(!$query) {
        $error = mysqli_error($conn);

        throw new Exception($error);
    }

    $result = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $row['value'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['nama_anime']));
        $row['id']    = $row['id'];

        $result[] = $row;
    }

    echo json_encode($result);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    $result['error'] = $e->getMessage();

    echo json_encode($result);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
```

The Jquery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        /*autocomplete muncul setelah user mengetikan minimal2 karakter */
        $(function() {  
            $( "#search" ).autocomplete({
                source: "data.php",  

            });
        });
    });
```